# Split string on the last occurrence of a character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, split

I have the string below:

`this sentence: should be: split after last colon: sentence`

I want to split the above string on the last colon (:) such that the resulting array will contain these two elements:

```
["this sentence: should be: splited after last colon:", "sentence"]
```

Comment: Question unclear. Do you want to split by a colon (keeping the colon), or by a space following a colon (throwing away the space)?

Comment: Did you read the question??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try simple code:

```
s = 'this sentence: should be: splited after last colon: sentence'
s =~ /(.*):(.*)?/
[ $1 << ':', $2 ]
# => ["this sentence: should be: splited after last colon:", " sentence"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a try with

```
str = "this sentence: should be: splited after last colon: sentence"
last_pos = str.rindex(/\:/)
arr = [str[0..last_pos].strip, str[last_pos + 1 .. str.length].strip]

=>["this sentence: should be: splited after last colon:", "sentence"]
```